# How to keep public key static, but rotate the certificate

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, public-key

In this article, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning, it reads:

"Even though Google rotates its certificates, the underlying public keys (within the certificate) remain static."

If I want to implement this so that I have a static public key, but can rotate the certificate, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just keep generating new CSRs from the same keypair.

Even more economically, just keep resubmitting the *same* CSR, as long as the underlying identification information hasn't changed. I've been doing this for many years.